# Disable one button in ngFor in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an add to list button in my component, that disables when a user clicks it once. Problem is when the user clicks the button next to the list item they want to add, it disable all the other list buttons also? I only want it to disable the one selected. My code so far is:

**component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let itunes of data | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: p } | filter:filter; let i = index">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12">
        <img class="align-self-start mr-5 mb-5 artwork" src="{{itunes.artworkUrl100}}" alt="image">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-sm-12">
        <h2 class="mt-0 d-inline-block text-truncate trunc">{{itunes.collectionName}}</h2>
        <h4 class="mt-0 mb-3">{{itunes.artistName}}</h4>
        <h5 class="mt-0 mb-3"><a href="{{itunes.collectionViewUrl}}" target="_blank">Listen</a></h5>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 mb-5 col-lg-2 col-sm-12">
        <a target="_blank"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg float-right"
            (click)="addSongToPlaylist(itunes); clicked = true;" [disabled]="clicked">
            <fa-icon [icon]="faPlus">
            </fa-icon>
          </button></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**component.ts** (Add function)

```
  addSongToPlaylist(itunes) {
    this.list.playlist.push(Object.assign({}, itunes));
    this.list.savePlaylist();
    console.log('Playlist - ', this.list.playlist);
  }
```

Any ideas, what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only one `clicked` property and all buttons have their `disabled` property bound to that property. That is why they are all enabled or disabled at the same time.

The simplest solution is to add a `clicked` property to the `Itunes` class, and modify its value when the button is clicked:

```
(click)="addSongToPlaylist(itunes); itunes.clicked = true;" [disabled]="itunes.clicked"
```

An alternative is to store the `clicked` value in a separate array, where each array item refers to an item of the data array.

Comment: After seeing @ChayMizrahi's answer, I was wondering: do you allow to click several buttons and disable each one, or can you have only one button disabled in the list?

Comment: I can click several buttons and disable each one

Answer (score 1):

Maybe do this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg float-right"
            (click)="addSongToPlaylist(itunes); clicked = i;" [disabled]="clicked===i">
            <fa-icon [icon]="faPlus">
            </fa-icon>
          </button>
```